# Moving files from bad external harddrive

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive

I use OSX mavericks. My external 1TB harddrive is partially unreadable. I want to salvage its content as much as possible. I have tried `dd` but it took almost a day, so I killed it, and it could not resume from where it left when I rerun it.
I am currently trying moving folders one by one with Finder.

[image: Moving folders]

My question is there any option in Finder to continue moving even if errors are detected ?

Comment: Which question? @patrix

Comment: Look at the top of your question, the link is displayed there. Also it might help to search for "getting data from a failing disc" and similar search terms here on the site, the issue has come up before. And just a personal observation: If the drive is failing, it will do more harm than good to run several copy processes in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Finder will always halt on Error. 
Have you tried Data Rescue 3? I've had good results using that in the past.
http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php